# Updating Open Graph Images in real time

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a website that generates a collage for a user and then allows them to share it on facebook. I have all the og tags setup, so when a user shares the page it will display an image preview. The problem here is that the first time a user shares the page no image preview appears because facebook has not crawled the page yet. If there someway to solve this, so the image preview shows up the very first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.

Just make sure you include the height and the width of the image as well in your OG definition.

Example:

```
   <meta property='og:image:width'        content='1000' />
   <meta property='og:image:height'       content='300' />
```